# How to validate twitter handle with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

There are several posts on Stack about this, and, sadly, almost all of them seem to neglect the instructions Twitter provides, even when they link to it:

https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/twitter-username-rules

- A handle can start or end with '_', but, my assumption is, not both.
- Total length of 15 chars
- Minimum length of 4 chars (which would include the '_' at either end)

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

There are several Stack threads that provide some good insight, but I think this puts it all together.

https://regex101.com/r/ruwkbI/1

`(?=.{4,15}$)(^_?[A-Za-z0-9]*$|^[A-Za-z0-9]*_?$)`

- `(?=.{4,15}$)` - between 4 and 15 characters
- `(^_?[A-Za-z0-9]*$|^[A-Za-z0-9]*_?$)` - starts with or ends with `_`, includes only regular alphanumerics
- I do not think you can use `\w` because it would match underscores and periods which are not valid characters

If you find an improvement to the above, please let me know.